# Data transfered from old iPad to a new iPad and iPhone; will a reset of the old iPad, wipe the data from the new devices?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Will factory reset of my old iPad2 remove my transferred data from the new iPad and iPhone? Everything's on the same account. Do I have to unsynch first?

Answer (score 3):

If you factory reset your iPad, you won't wipe the data from your other devices.

To give you some perspective, it would be counter intuitive if you lost your phone and remotely wiped your device only to have all your other devices wiped as well.

That being said.... don't have the expectation that your other devices are back ups of your data.  While you will have access to your data in the case of losing a device, if you inadvertently delete your data (all your photos as an example) that change will propagate to all your other devices.

Comment: Absolutely not clear what your answer is. Is not resetting to factory setting deleting all the data, which you are saying would wipe all on the other devises, since it’s identical account and all the data.

Comment: Resetting the device doesn't send a "delete" command.  It reinitialized the device to the state it came from the factory.  That will *never* be propagated to your other devices.  You selecting data and pressing delete will be propagated.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you transferred to to the new devices space and not iCloud space and when you factory reset don’t accidentally reset your iCloud storage your fine. Just be care because some apps like notes, photos, contacts could be stored through other means.